Bicep `for` loop breaks on policySetDefinition when assigning array to `policyDefinitions` where object property has `value: '[parameters(\'tag0\')]'`
When I deploy the Bicep below, the resource policySetDefinition0 fails with the error message "The deployment 'PolicyDefinitionBatch_20240808-130023' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s). Status Message: Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/DeleteMe - Demo Fail' at line '50' and column '9'. 'The template parameter 'tag0' is not found. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax-parameters for usage details.' (Code:InvalidTemplate)".
Using the for loop was my initial approach. After debugging and viewing the JSON version in the deployment attempt, I tried directly specifying the array indices with policySetDefinition2 and that worked. I was aware of another way of creating arrays by using the map lambda and that also worked in policySetDefinition1. I have successfully used the for loop to assign arrays of objects to properties on resources like application gateway, but those did not have weird string assignment value: '[parameters(\'tag0\')]' that needs to be passed for the policy set definition.
Though I have a solution with the map lambda, I'd like to understand why the for loop doesn't work in this case.
targetScope = 'managementGroup'

var policyDefinitions = [
  'DeleteMe - Demo Fail 00'
  'DeleteMe - Demo Fail 01'
  'DeleteMe - Demo Fail 02'
]

resource policyDefinition 'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions@2023-04-01' = [
  for item in policyDefinitions: {
    name: replace(item, ' ', '')
    properties: {
      parameters: {
        tag0: {
          type: 'string'
        }
        tag1: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      }
      policyRule: {
        if: {
          anyof: [
            {
              field: '[concat(\'tags[\',parameters(\'tag0\'), \']\')]'
              exists: 'false'
            }
            {
              field: '[concat(\'tags[\',parameters(\'tag1\'), \']\')]'
              exists: 'false'
            }
          ]
        }
        then: {
          effect: 'audit'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

resource policySetDefinition0 'Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions@2023-04-01' = {
  name: 'DeleteMe - Demo Fail'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'DeleteMe - Demo Fail'
    description: 'Demo Fail'
    parameters: {
      tag0: {
        type: 'string'
      }
      tag1: {
        type: 'string'
      }
    }
    policyDefinitions: [
      for item in policyDefinitions: {
        policyDefinitionReferenceId: 'Audit Tags for ${item}'
        policyDefinitionId: managementGroupResourceId(
          'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions',
          '${replace(item, ' ', '')}'
        )
        parameters: {
          tag0: {
            value: '[parameters(\'tag0\')]'
          }
          tag1: {
            value: '[parameters(\'tag1\')]'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  dependsOn: [policyDefinition]
}

resource policySetDefinition1 'Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions@2023-04-01' = {
  name: 'DeleteMe - Demo Lambda'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'DeleteMe - Demo Lambda'
    description: 'Demo Lambda'
    parameters: {
      tag0: {
        type: 'string'
      }
      tag1: {
        type: 'string'
      }
    }
    policyDefinitions: map(policyDefinitions, policyDefinition => {
      policyDefinitionReferenceId: 'Audit Tags for ${policyDefinition}'
      policyDefinitionId: managementGroupResourceId(
        'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions',
        '${replace(policyDefinition, ' ', '')}'
      )
      parameters: {
        tag0: {
          value: '[parameters(\'tag0\')]'
        }
        tag1: {
          value: '[parameters(\'tag1\')]'
        }
      }
    })
  }
  dependsOn: [policyDefinition]
}

resource policySetDefinition2 'Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions@2023-04-01' = {
  name: 'DeleteMe - Demo Success'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'DeleteMe - Demo Success'
    description: 'Demo Success'
    parameters: {
      tag0: {
        type: 'string'
      }
      tag1: {
        type: 'string'
      }
    }
    policyDefinitions: [
      {
        policyDefinitionReferenceId: 'Audit Tags for ${policyDefinitions[0]}'
        policyDefinitionId: managementGroupResourceId(
          'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions',
          '${replace(policyDefinitions[0], ' ', '')}'
        )
        parameters: {
          tag0: {
            value: '[parameters(\'tag0\')]'
          }
          tag1: {
            value: '[parameters(\'tag1\')]'
          }
        }
      }
      {
        policyDefinitionReferenceId: 'Audit Tags for ${policyDefinitions[1]}'
        policyDefinitionId: managementGroupResourceId(
          'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions',
          '${replace(policyDefinitions[1], ' ', '')}'
        )
        parameters: {
          tag0: {
            value: '[parameters(\'tag0\')]'
          }
          tag1: {
            value: '[parameters(\'tag1\')]'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  dependsOn: [policyDefinition]
}

Bit of PowerShell to help with deploying.
$deploymentTimestamp = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd-HHmmss')
$deploymentParameterSplat = @{
  Name              = "PolicyDefinitionBatch_$($deploymentTimestamp)"
  ManagementGroupId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.Id
  Location          = 'East US 2'
  TemplateFile      = '.\demoFail.bicep'
}
New-AzManagementGroupDeployment @deploymentParameterSplat -Verbose

Here is the deployment result.

The template for the deployment as viewed in the Azure portal.
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/managementGroupDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "variables": {
        "policyDefinitions": [
            "DeleteMe - Demo Fail 00",
            "DeleteMe - Demo Fail 01",
            "DeleteMe - Demo Fail 02"
        ]
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
            "apiVersion": "2023-04-01",
            "name": "[replace(variables('policyDefinitions')[copyIndex()], ' ', '')]",
            "properties": {
                "parameters": {
                    "tag0": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "tag1": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "policyRule": {
                    "if": {
                        "anyof": [
                            {
                                "field": "[[concat('tags[',parameters('tag0'), ']')]",
                                "exists": "false"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "[[concat('tags[',parameters('tag1'), ']')]",
                                "exists": "false"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "effect": "audit"
                    }
                }
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "policyDefinition",
                "count": "[length(variables('policyDefinitions'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions",
            "apiVersion": "2023-04-01",
            "name": "DeleteMe - Demo Fail",
            "dependsOn": [
                "policyDefinition"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "copy": [
                    {
                        "name": "policyDefinitions",
                        "count": "[length(variables('policyDefinitions'))]",
                        "input": {
                            "policyDefinitionReferenceId": "[format('Audit Tags for {0}', variables('policyDefinitions')[copyIndex('policyDefinitions')])]",
                            "policyDefinitionId": "[managementGroupResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions', format('{0}', replace(variables('policyDefinitions')[copyIndex('policyDefinitions')], ' ', '')))]",
                            "parameters": {
                                "tag0": {
                                    "value": "[[parameters('tag0')]"
                                },
                                "tag1": {
                                    "value": "[[parameters('tag1')]"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "displayName": "DeleteMe - Demo Fail",
                "description": "Demo Fail",
                "parameters": {
                    "tag0": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "tag1": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions",
            "apiVersion": "2023-04-01",
            "name": "DeleteMe - Demo Lambda",
            "dependsOn": [
                "policyDefinition"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "DeleteMe - Demo Lambda",
                "description": "Demo Lambda",
                "parameters": {
                    "tag0": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "tag1": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "policyDefinitions": "[map(variables('policyDefinitions'), lambda('policyDefinition', createObject('policyDefinitionReferenceId', format('Audit Tags for {0}', lambdaVariables('policyDefinition')), 'policyDefinitionId', managementGroupResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions', format('{0}', replace(lambdaVariables('policyDefinition'), ' ', ''))), 'parameters', createObject('tag0', createObject('value', '[parameters(''tag0'')]'), 'tag1', createObject('value', '[parameters(''tag1'')]')))))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions",
            "apiVersion": "2023-04-01",
            "name": "DeleteMe - Demo Success",
            "dependsOn": [
                "policyDefinition"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "DeleteMe - Demo Success",
                "description": "Demo Success",
                "parameters": {
                    "tag0": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "tag1": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "policyDefinitions": [
                    {
                        "policyDefinitionReferenceId": "[format('Audit Tags for {0}', variables('policyDefinitions')[0])]",
                        "policyDefinitionId": "[managementGroupResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions', format('{0}', replace(variables('policyDefinitions')[0], ' ', '')))]",
                        "parameters": {
                            "tag0": {
                                "value": "[[parameters('tag0')]"
                            },
                            "tag1": {
                                "value": "[[parameters('tag1')]"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "policyDefinitionReferenceId": "[format('Audit Tags for {0}', variables('policyDefinitions')[1])]",
                        "policyDefinitionId": "[managementGroupResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions', format('{0}', replace(variables('policyDefinitions')[1], ' ', '')))]",
                        "parameters": {
                            "tag0": {
                                "value": "[[parameters('tag0')]"
                            },
                            "tag1": {
                                "value": "[[parameters('tag1')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}


The error you encountered due to the for loop in the policySetDefinition0 resource relates to how parameters are referenced and utilized in the deployment template, particularly the syntax of the Bicep for loop.
Here is the correct bicep code to create policy definition using for loop and 3 Initiative.
targetScope = 'subscription'
var policyDefinitions = [
  'DeleteMe - Demo Fail 00'
  'DeleteMe - Demo Fail 01'
  'DeleteMe - Demo Fail 02'
]

resource policyDefinition 'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions@2023-04-01' = [
  for item in policyDefinitions: {
    name: replace(item, ' ', '')
    properties: {
      parameters: {
        tagName: {
          type: 'string'
          defaultValue: 'testing'
        }
        tagValue: {
          type: 'string'
          defaultValue: 'production'
        }
      }
      policyRule: {
        if: {
          anyof: [
            {
              field: '[concat(\'tags[\', parameters(\'tagName\'), \']\')]'
              exists: 'false'
            }
            {
              field: '[concat(\'tags[\', parameters(\'tagValue\'), \']\')]'
              exists: 'false'
            }
          ]
        }
        then: {
          effect: 'audit'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

// Define policy set definitions
resource policySetDefinitionFail 'Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions@2023-04-01' = {
  name: 'DeleteMe - Demo Fail'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'DeleteMe - Demo Fail'
    description: 'Demo Fail'
    policyDefinitions: [
      for item in policyDefinitions: {
        policyDefinitionReferenceId: 'Audit Tags for ${item}'
        policyDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId(
          'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions',
          replace(item, ' ', '')
        )
        parameters: {
          tagName: {
            value: 'testing'
          }
          tagValue: {
            value: 'production'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  dependsOn: [policyDefinition]
}

resource policySetDefinitionLambda 'Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions@2023-04-01' = {
  name: 'DeleteMe - Demo Lambda'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'DeleteMe - Demo Lambda'
    description: 'Demo Lambda'
    policyDefinitions: [
      for item in policyDefinitions: {
        policyDefinitionReferenceId: 'Audit Tags for ${item}'
        policyDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId(
          'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions',
          replace(item, ' ', '')
        )
        parameters: {
          tagName: {
            value: 'testing'
          }
          tagValue: {
            value: 'production'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  dependsOn: [policyDefinition]
}

resource policySetDefinitionSuccess 'Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions@2023-04-01' = {
  name: 'DeleteMe - Demo Success'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'DeleteMe - Demo Success'
    description: 'Demo Success'
    policyDefinitions: [
      {
        policyDefinitionReferenceId: 'Audit Tags for ${policyDefinitions[0]}'
        policyDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId(
          'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions',
          replace(policyDefinitions[0], ' ', '')
        )
        parameters: {
          tagName: {
            value: 'testing'
          }
          tagValue: {
            value: 'production'
          }
        }
      }
      {
        policyDefinitionReferenceId: 'Audit Tags for ${policyDefinitions[1]}'
        policyDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId(
          'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions',
          replace(policyDefinitions[1], ' ', '')
        )
        parameters: {
          tagName: {
            value: 'testing'
          }
          tagValue: {
            value: 'production'
          }
        }
      }
      {
        policyDefinitionReferenceId: 'Audit Tags for ${policyDefinitions[2]}'
        policyDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId(
          'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions',
          replace(policyDefinitions[2], ' ', '')
        )
        parameters: {
          tagName: {
            value: 'testing'
          }
          tagValue: {
            value: 'production'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  dependsOn: [policyDefinition]
}

Policy output

The policy definitions are created with the name DeleteMe-DemoFail00

